# Access data from sqlite db in Google chrome Extension

Tags: c++, sqlite, google-chrome, npapi, firebreath

I am creating a Google chrome Extension in this extension I want to access(query) data from "SqliteDb".The SqliteDb placed in Temp folder.
 How will i do this.please suggest me.if have any need of using plugins then provide me link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm rather confused; to me this seems pretty obvious.  If you want to access sqlite from a NPAPI plugin (which you can then use from inside a chrome extension) you need to embed the [sqlite libary](http://sqlite.org/download.html).

There should be no reason that you can't use normal C (or C++) libraries for database access from within your plugin.

Comment: i am new in plugins development so please suggest me how to use sqlite library in NPAIP plugins.i create a NPAPI plugins by Fire Breath so how include sqlite library and access data from sqlitedb.

Comment: You need to understand that this is *not* a plugin question; it's a C++ question. On the FireBreath website do a search for Libraries that will tell you how to specify additional link libraries in the cmake config; that's not a plugin question either, but it'll help to know it.  Then you need to learn how to use the sqlite library in C++. I recommend doing some searches for something like "sqlite c++ example" on google.